# handlebars js - How to avoid replacing handlebars placeholders / tokens with empty string, if they dont exist in the object passed in

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

handlebars js - How to avoid replacing handlebars placeholders / tokens with empty string, if they dont exist in the object passed in

I have template like this
let str = "location = {{item.businessLocation}}";

And Data Object like this
let data = {"item":{"name":"Mathew"}};

As we can see the placeholder or variable {{item.businessLocation}} is missing in the data object.
I do not want the placeholder to be replaced with "" when it is rendered by Handlebars.

I tried implementing the helperMissing helper like below, but it did not work, because the placeholder has a dot in between.

```
handlebars.registerHelper('helperMissing', function(token) {
    return '{{'+token+'}}';
});
```

Is there any to have handlebars not replace tokens / placeholders with "" , if they don't exist in the object passed in?

I always get the below output

```
location = ""
```

What I need is

```
location = {{item.businessLocation}}
```

( since item.businessLocation is not present in the data object )

Comment: I can see achieving this only with a custom helper and I think it would get a little ugly. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/bpoezqga/

Comment: Thanks . This will work . But we have to add the custom helper with every placeholders I guess ... But thanks a lot.